# How do I use seq() and rep() and paste() to generate a specific vector?

Tags: r, vector, seq, rep

I am trying to generate the following vector without using
`c()`:
`a1, b2, b3, c4, c4, c6`. I am having a really hard time with this. I tried to make a simple python function to help visualize it:

```
listy = []
size = 2
lets = ["a", "b", "c"]
iterator = 1
for i in range(1, 4):
    let = lets[i-1]
    for j in range(3-size):
        listy.append(let + str(iterator))
        iterator += 1
    size -= 1
print(listy)
```

But I can't get anything similar to work in R. I would greatly appreciate some help.
About the closest I've gotten is this:

```
paste(rep(1:6), rep(letters[1:3]))
```

But obviously that's way off. Am I going to have to use for loops to generate this? It seems like there must be a simpler way...
I am new to vector generation and the functions don't seem intuitive at all. If you could just give a poke in the right direction I'm sure I could figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be :

```
vec <- letters[1:3]
tmp <- rep(vec, seq_along(vec))
paste0(tmp, seq_along(tmp))
#[1] "a1" "b2" "b3" "c4" "c5" "c6"
```

By hardcoding this is similar to :

```
paste0(rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 1:3), 1:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(vec, seq_along(vec), FUN = paste0))
```